# There is no result type defined for type 'redirect-action' mapped with name 'success'

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, naming-conventions, camelcasing

```xml
<action name="saveGetStarted" class="com.sample.action.GetStartedAction" method="save">
      <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
      <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
          <param name="actionName">preQualification</param>
          <param name="customerId">${customerId}</param>
      </result>
      <result name="input">/jsp/getStarted.jsp</result>
      <result name="error">/jsp/getStarted.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="preQualification"  class="com.sample.action.PreQualificationAction">
    <result name="success">/jsp/preQualification.jsp</result>
    <result name="input"  >/jsp/preQualification.jsp</result>
</action>
```

With `struts2-core-2.0.12.jar` it works fine, but after the update to `struts2-core-2.1.6.jar`, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'redirect-action' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'redirectAction'? - result - file:/D:/eclipse-indigo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Fundation/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:54
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:613)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:364)
    ... 26 more
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: My idea would be to read the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using old notation for action redirect result. Change `redirect-action` to `redirectAction`.

Answer (score 5):

In Struts 2.3.x some code is changed like **redirect-action** is changed to  **redirectAction**

So you have to declare it like this way -

```
<action name="saveGetStarted" class="com.sample.action.GetStartedAction" method="save">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">preQualification</param>
                <param name="customerId">${customerId}</param>
            </result>
            <result name="input">/jsp/getStarted.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/jsp/getStarted.jsp</result>
          </action>

         <action name="preQualification"  class="com.sample.action.PreQualificationAction"  method="excute">
                <result name="success">/jsp/preQualification.jsp</result>
                <result name="input">/jsp/preQualification.jsp</result>
          </action>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Struts `2.1.0`, all the default **result names** and **interceptors names** have changed [`Letter case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles), from the old `spinal-case` to the new `camelCase`.

From the [Struts `2.1.1` release version notes](http://%20struts.apache.org/docs/version-notes-211.html#VersionNotes2.1.1-Backwardcompatibilityissueswithpreviousversions):

> #### Backward compatibility issues with previous versions
>
> Since `2.1.0`: All default result names and interceptor names are now in camelCase 
> (eg. was `redirect-action`, is now `redirectAction`)
>
> ...